# how to get degrees of a specific X Position in an object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, angle, orbital-mechanics

This is my method to move squares around a circle like satelites does on planets:

```
-(CGPoint)circularMovement:(float)degrees radius:(CGFloat)radius{        
        float x = (planet.position.x + planet.radius) *cos(degrees);
        float y = (planet.position.y + planet.radius) *sin(degrees);

        CGPoint posicion = CGPointMake(x, y);
        return posicion;
}
```

As you can see, I get an x and y position of my satelite, and calling this method with degrees++ I got a circular movement around planets.

But my problem with this movement sistem is I need the degrees of `satelite.position.x+satelite.size.width/2` to detect collisions with another object moving around with the same movement-sistem.

Anybody knows how to get this value??

Answer (score 1):

Just do same calculations, but backwards.

In your example you knew: *planet.position*, *planet.radius*, *degrees* and you had to find *x* and *y* for that `CGPoint`.

Now you know: *planet.position*, *planet.radius* and that `CGPoint` and you need to find degrees.

From your formula:

```
float x = (planet.position.x + planet.radius) *cos(degrees);
```

you can find your degrees:

```
cos(degrees) = x / (planet.position.x + planet.radius);
```

For example:

```
cos(x) = 1 / 2;
```

then

```
x = acos(1/2);
x = 60 degrees or Pi/3 rads
```

Comment: I've tried this : 
cos(degrees) = x / (planet.position.x + planet.radius);

But without success.
And I don't understand the rest of the example->
For example:

cos(x) = 1 / 2;
then

x = acos(1/2);
x = 60 degrees or Pi/3 rads

Comment: @user3033437 it's basic mathematics, not code. You can write code to find *degrees* yourself

Comment: note that sin, cos, cos etc. and SpriteKit use radians not degrees so you will have to convert: `rad=deg/180*M_PI`